# How to fix RecyclerView's StaggeredGridLayoutManager on scrolling separates the content and fly randomly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I was trying to fetch remote images which I've an API and display it in a Masonry Grid (Pinterest Style).

At first I was using simple GridView it was working perfectly but without the Masonry style. Then, after various research I was finally using:

1. `Fresco` to fetch Image & Cache
2. `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to display the images from the API.
3. Custom layout with `SimpleDraweeView` to display each item.
4. My own custom Adapter "MasonryAdapter" to bind the data to the view.

In the Custom layout, I set SimpleDraweeView with:

```
layout_with = match_parent
layout_height = wrap_content
```

Then, in my adapter I've set the correct aspect ratio to each of the image, as in my API I can get the images' width & height easily.

```
holder.contentImage.aspectRatio = image.width.toFloat() / image.height.toFloat()
```

Though at first moment everything looked acceptable but after scrolling I found everything breaks apart. I'm very new to `Android` & `Kotlin`, please ask if you need anything. Here I'm attaching a GIF to what is happening.

[image: Preview]

If image removed please check it here: https://ibb.co/dy0EjH

Comment: I think you might be doing something wrong in how you are notifying the adapter of changed data. Can you add your `RecyclerView` and fetching image code?

Comment: Constraint layout breaks when being used in a recycler view. You can verify this easily with a simple very simple case. I filed an issue, which was fixed very quickly (can't find the link right now). This MIGHT be your problem. Try updating your constraint layout dependency. If that doesn't resolve the problem, you might have to use a different view group.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, I was using textview inside Constraint layout.

Constraint layout breaks when used in a recycler view and what fixed my problem (as @AutonomousApps mentioned in the comments):

I just updated Constraint layout version ( to the latest stable version at the moment) from **1.0.1** to **1.1.1**.

**So if you are using Constraint layout just update to the latest stable version and this maybe will fix your problem!**

(see below images for screenshots)

[image]

*unexpected behaviour*

[image]

*after updated constraint layout version*

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue with my Note taking app

Just simply make the height to 0dp

Cause when it's wrap_content, the staggered view has variable size of the list so at the end due to variable size the view stops at half (cause the recycler view calculated the size less than needed)

So using 0dp / match_parent makes the size of the recycler view constant, that's why we can scroll it through